# Why is relative velocity not defined on curved manifolds, is relative distance also not defined?

Tags: general-relativity, differential-geometry, distance

I understand that relative velocity is not defined on curved manifolds because you are comparing vectors from different tangent spaces. Lets say body A is moving vith velocity $v_A$ and body B with velocity $v_B$.

My question is: can't you parallel transport the vector $v_B$ along a geodesic to the tangent space where $v_A$ is and there compare their velocities? Since by parallel transporting you are not chaning the vector, isnt't it the same as having a relative velocity? Or does the metric change the components of the vector by parallel transporting so it wouldn't correspond at all to reality?

What about the distances? I've already studied a little bit of cosmology so I know there are multiple distances defined like the standard candle, redshift, comoving, proper etc. Isn't proper distance the real distance we measure in real life if we could have a big ruler? Why define other distances then?

Comment: That parallel transport changes a vector is usually one of the first things we demonstrate in lectures and textbooks about Riemann manifolds. You can check for yourself by transporting a vector on the surface of a sphere, for instance. Wikipedia has the usual diagram for this case: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parallel_transport

Comment: Thank you, Im actually still in high school and teach myself. I'll look into in.

Comment: You are welcome. The basics of manifolds are certainly not beyond high school level and you can study some of it on your own without problems in my opinion. We do teach path-dependent phenomena at the high school level when we talk about non-conservative forces, so the basic phenomenology is not all that unusual, even if the mechanism is slightly different.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> My question is: can't you parallel transport the vector vB
> along a geodesic to the tangent space where vA is and there compare their velocities?

The first two things that mathematicians like to do when they develop a new concept is that they like to prove existence and uniqueness. Unfortunately, a geodesic path between two arbitrary events in an arbitrary spacetime fails on both fronts. It is neither guaranteed to exist nor, if it exists, is it guaranteed to be unique. As such it is not a solid foundation for building other concepts like distance or relative velocity.

Comment: concrete example for OP to think about: the (round) sphere $S^2$, where the geodesics are great circles.